# Using Components folder instead of Pages

Tags: directory, architecture, components, blazor

With Blazor being component based and components can be on multiple pages, I would like to use a Components folder (similar to Features) instead of Pages.  For example, in addition to having a Dashboard folder for the page component, there would be individual folders for each component in the SPA such as Chart, Gauge, List, etc.  This would eliminate the need for a Shared folder in Features.  All components can be accessed in one place and used by other page components.

Starting with the Blazor Server template for .NET 5.0, changing the Pages folder to Components and changing the @namespace to Blazor.Server.Components, I am getting the following error.

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }.

How should the below endpoint in Startup.cs be specified to change the reference to the Components folder? Anything else to do?

> endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In blazor server-side you need to tell blazor where your root page folder is:

```
private static void AddRootDirectory(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages(options =>
    {
        options.RootDirectory = "/Views/Pages";
     });
}
```

You can use what ever folder structure you like, just remember that `.razor` files infer there namespace from the folder structure. If for example you create the structure `/views/components` you should add this path to your imports or have a using statement on any page that needs to find it. You will note by default the `\Shared` folder is mentioned in the `_imports.razor`

You can override the inferred namespace with the `@namespace` directive on the `.razor` page.

Web assembly will find pages in the current assembly simply because of the `@page` attribute. Server-side you need to tell the server where the root page is as shown above.

Comment: Many thanks.  I though razor folder directives were not required in Blazor, including server side.  Now I know, "and knowing is half the battle."

Answer (score 0):

You can create components in whatever configuration of folders you want, already.  The only thing you need to leave is some of the defaults stuff like _Host.

So go ahead:
(1)  Make a folder called "Components"
(2)  Make some .razor components in your folder
(3)  Use them in your pages.